# How do I get Vagrant to find the latest (homestead) box

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have the latest version of vagrant, I added a `homestead` box via `vagrant box add laravel/homestead`, I checked out the latest `homestead` from `github` via

```
git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git homestead
cd homestead
git checkout release
```

but when I do `vagrant up` it cannot find the `v10.1.1` box and tries to download `v9.7.2` instead.

```
>vagrant -v
Vagrant 2.2.14

>vagrant box update
==> homestead: Checking for updates to 'laravel/homestead'
    homestead: Latest installed version: 10.1.1
    homestead: Version constraints: ~> 9
    homestead: Provider: virtualbox
==> homestead: Box 'laravel/homestead' (v10.1.1) is running the latest version.

>vagrant box list
laravel/homestead  (virtualbox, 10.1.1)
```

```
>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'homestead' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> homestead: [vagrant-hostsupdater] Checking for host entries
==> homestead: [vagrant-hostsupdater]   found entry for: 192.168.10.10 homestead
==> homestead: [vagrant-hostsupdater]   found entry for: 192.168.10.10 laravel.test
==> homestead: Box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    homestead: Box Provider: virtualbox
    homestead: Box Version: ~> 9
==> homestead: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
    homestead: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/homestead
==> homestead: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v9.7.2) for provider: virtualbox
    homestead: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/9.7.2/providers/virtualbox.box
==> homestead: Box download is resuming from prior download progress
```

I see that I can use `version: 10.1.1` in my `Homestead.yaml` but why is vagrant trying to get v9 instead of using v10 I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default setting in the laravel/homstead project is using the version 9.
So you have to modify the following setting in **/Users/(name)/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb**

```
config.vm.box_version = settings['version'] ||= '‍‍‍‍‍~> 9'
```

to

```
config.vm.box_version = settings['version'] ||= '‍‍‍‍‍>= 10.1.1'
```

After saving the changes, you can start the box with:

```
vagrant up
```

Comment: Thanks. I see that I can also change the version in `Homestead.yaml` but it just seems weird to me that it's not using the latest version by default.

Comment: If you think that the answer helped you to fix the issue, you can accept it as the solution of your problem.